# Are android studio modules and eclipse projects the same thing?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

If yes, can modules be ran stand-alone as in eclipse projects ?

Also, bonus points. If I save a variable in MainActivity.java can I pass it to a different java class in a a different module? If yes, how?

Comment: How can you declare a static variable and then send it to another module?   Could you elaborate?